# Celery group.apply_async().join() never returns

Tags: python, celery

Consider the following script

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import group
app = Celery()
app.conf.update(
    broker_url='pyamqp://guest@localhost//',
    result_backend='redis://localhost',
)

@app.task
def my_calc(data):
    for i in range(100):
        data[0]=data[0]/1.04856
        data[1]=data[1]/1.02496
    return data

def compute(parallel_tasks):
    tasks=[]
    for i in range(parallel_tasks):
        tasks.append([i+1.3,i+2.65])

    job = group([my_calc.s(task) for task in tasks])
    results = job.apply_async().join(timeout=120)

    #for result in results:
    #    print(result.get(timeout=20))


def start(parallel_tasks,iterations):
    for i in range(iterations):
        print(i)
        compute(parallel_tasks)
```

The script executes a given number of tasks (`parallel_tasks`) in a given number of iterations (`iterations`) using celery's [group function](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)

The problem is that, the more task I submit in a single iteration (the greater the `parallel_tasks` input parameter) the more likely that the execution of the batch will time out because of an unknown reason. The workers don't get overloaded, when the timeout happens workers are already idle.

Calling `start(2,100000)` works just fine.
Calling `start(20,40)` stops around the 10th iteration.

The issue is independent from broker and backend types. My primary config uses RabbitMQ as broker and Redis as backend, but I've tried vice versa, RabbitMQ only and Redis only configuration too.

I start the worker just the standard way: `worker -A tasks -l info`

**Environment:**

```
Miniconda - Python 3.6.6 (see requirements.txt for details below)
Debian 9 running in Virtualbox. VM Config: 4 cores and 8GB RAM
Redis 4.0.11
RabbitMQ 3.6.6 on Erlang 19.2.1

**Output of celery -A tasks report**
software -> celery:4.2.1 (windowlicker) kombu:4.2.1 py:3.6.6
billiard:3.5.0.4 py-amqp:2.3.2
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:pyamqp results:redis://localhost/
```

RabbitMQ log contains the following errors:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Sep-2018::17:31:42 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1688.0> (127.0.0.1:52602 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```